# Find screen position of the Caret in windows CE. (equiv to GetGUIThreadInfo?)

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ce, sip

I'm creating a custom soft-input-panel and would like to find the position of the Caret. I could then move the SIP out of way if it is covering the position where text is being entered.

It sounds like in windows the way to do this would be with GetGUIThreadInfo(). However, it appears that API is not supported in Windows CE (specifically CE 6.0 R3).

Is there an alternate method of finding this same information? A way of determining the active window and where text would be entered on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The caret should only be displayed on the window that has focus and is active.  How about something like:

```
POINT cp;
GetCaretPos(&cp); // in client coordinates
HWND hActive=GetActiveWindow();
```

If you needed more information (like a specific child window), you could convert the point returned by `GetCaretPos()` into screen coordinates, then use `WindowFromPoint()` to convert back to a specific (child) window handle.

Comment: Corey, this was a while ago that I was dealing with this, but IIRC the reason I could not go with a solution like you suggested was because on Windows-CE 6.0 GetCaretPos fails if you are not in the same process as the window owning the caret. Since I was trying to access this information from an SIP, I was not able to use this method because the I was trying to find the position of the caret in a different process.